# efficient way of concat columns depending on condition

Tags: python, pandas

MRE:

```
dictionary = {'2018-10': 50, '2018-11': 76}
df = pd.DataFrame({
    "date":["2018-10", "2018-10", "2018-10", "2018-11","2018-11"]
})
```

that looks like (I have milions of rows and multiple rows):

```
      date
0   2018-10
1   2018-10
2   2018-10
3   2018-11
4   2018-11
```

depending on date, in the dictionary there is number associated to it. I want to concatenate that associated number into date column (using vectorization).

so my desired dataframe would look like:

```
         date
0   2018-10 (50)
1   2018-10 (50)
2   2018-10 (50)
3   2018-11 (76)
4   2018-11 (76)
```

my date column has datatype string.

**Current solution:**
I could use apply lambda:

```
 df["date"] = df["date"].apply(lambda row:row + f" ({dictionary[row]})")
```

however I am wondering if there is any way to do it vectorized way since I have millions of rows and do not want to go row by row.

**EDIT:**
Now I think of it I don't think there can be a vectorized way since depending on date I need to concat different numbers.

Comment: There are indeed `pandas.Series.apply` and a `pandas.Series.map` methods. Perhaps those what you're looking for? I think your last snippet is in fact working code. Did you try it?

Comment: last code is working but I am wondering if there is method using vectorization

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`pd.Series.map`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html) can take a `dict` as the mapping, and strings and string columns can be added, so it's actually as easy as

```
df['date'] = df['date'] + ' (' + df['date'].map(dictionary).astype(str) + ')'
```

Comment: Thanks I've just realized there cannot be a way of doing this in vectorized way. This would be more efficient then apply.

Comment: Why is this more efficient than apply?

Answer (score 0):

So I'm not 100% that this is the fastest way to do things but it is fairly simple.

```
data = {'2018-10': 50, '2018-11': 76}
df = pd.DataFrame({
    "date":["2018-10", "2018-10", "2018-10", "2018-11","2018-11"]
})
df["data"] = df.date.apply(lambda x: data[x])
```

Which yields:

```
      date  data
0  2018-10    50
1  2018-10    50
2  2018-10    50
3  2018-11    76
4  2018-11    76
```

Alternatively to `df.date.apply(lambda x: data[x])` you could use

```
df.apply(lambda x: data[x['date']],axis=1)
```

Which I believe would perform similarly but it's less readable imo.

Comment: Then concat two columns?

Comment: You don't need to concat anything because you are assigning the result to the column `data`.

Comment: I want numbers inside date column.

Comment: `df["date"] = df.date.apply(lambda x: x+" ({})".format(data[x]))` but why?

Comment: that's what I am doing above but I want to use vectorization